# Yii Framework: ajax и аутентификация

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

Добрый день, пожалуйста, помогите. 
Есть контроллер NewDb :

```
class NewDbController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->render('index');           
    }

    public function actionHomeowners()
    {                
            $sql='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  HomeownersDB (
            id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,    
            email VARCHAR(255) default "",
            INDEX (id)

            )  ';
        Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute(); 
    }
```

Действие Homeowners отправляет запрос на создание БД HomeownersDB. 
Если я захожу на сайт как Guest в контролер site.ru/NewDb и отправляю ajax запрос

```
$.ajax({
   //Берем из data имя "Homeowners"
   var str= $(this).data('query');

    type: "POST",
    url: str, // Homeowners     
    }).done(function(msg) {  
           $('.query').html('ГОТОВО');          
    }) .fail(function() {  
        $('.query').html('error');
    });
```

проблем не возникает -  БД создается.
Но если я вхожу после того как ввел admin/admin, то ajax не работает. Я могу обратиться по прямой ссылке site.ru/NewDb/Homeowners и работать будет, но почему не получается с помощью ajax? Что изменилось?
Спасибо.

Comment: Может Вы в admin/admin забыли подключить jquery?

Comment: Может быть, а как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, в ведущий контроллер пишите:

> Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCoreScript('jquery');

Comment: Не пойму, куда именно нужно написать?